# How to plot previous ohlc4 HMA candle wick high and low for a stoploss??? Pinescript

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have the candles plotted and I'm just trying to plot my stoploss in ticks with the previous candles wick high and low. Low for Longs and High for Shorts.

I can get it to plot using the real close and heikien ashi but I would like to have the stoploss with the plotted HMA candles that are on the chart.

Any help would be awesome and big time thanks in advance,

Paul

```
    //@version=5
    strategy("Hull Candles", overlay=true, margin_long=100, 
    margin_short=100)

len = input(10, title= "Hull Length")
lenclose = input(1, title="Hull Close Lenth")

//Candle values

o = ta.hma(open,len)
c = ta.hma(close,len)
h = ta.hma(high,len)
l = ta.hma(low,len)
t = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
t2 = ticker.heikinashi(t)


ohlcFour = ta.hma(ohlc4,len)

colorBody = ohlcFour > ohlcFour[1] ? color.white : #6F00FF
plotcandle(o,h,l,c, color=colorBody, title= "Hull Candles")

//Stoploss labels
longstoploss = request.security(ohlc4, timeframe.period, low[1])
shortstoploss = request.security(ohlc4, timeframe.period, high[1])
longstop = str.tostring(longstoploss)
shortstop = str.tostring(shortstoploss)

Longstoplabel = label.new(x=bar_index,y=na, text = longstop, yloc = yloc.belowbar,textcolor=color.white, color=#000000,size = size.normal,style = label.style_none)
Shortstoplabel = label.new(x=bar_index,y=na, text = shortstop, yloc = yloc.abovebar,textcolor= #6F00FF, color=#000000,size = size.normal,style = label.style_none)

label.delete(Longstoplabel[1])
label.delete(Shortstoplabel[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what you need, but if you want the hull candle low,

```
Hull_Candle_low = ta.valuewhen(close,l,0)
```

so if you want to put the stoploss at the previous hull candle low, that would be `Hull_Candle_low[1]`

same thing with shorts/high

```
Hull_Candle_high = ta.valuewhen(close,h,0)
```

and the previous hull candle high is `Hull_Candle_high[1]`

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yes I would like the Hull candle low... But the low in tick value because if we just plot the low it plots the full price like this... 3489.9868008668. If we use the tick value for the futures charts then the price would be 3500. It would make for a clearer chart and easy reference instead of the larger number.

Comment: that's solvable as well ..
just use `math.round_to_mintick(Hull_Candle_low )`

Comment: u can also use `math.round(number)`
and if you want to round to nearest 1000 , u can use a custom function like this `RoundToThousands(value) =>
    math.round(value / 1000.0) * 1000`
then `RoundToThousands( any number)`
if u want to round to nearest 100, use the a similar function , but instead of 100 , just use 100